# Is there a way to add a title to this word cloud in quanteda?

Tags: r, plot, title, word-cloud, quanteda

```
library(quanteda)
library(quanteda.textplots)

corpus_subset(data_corpus_inaugural, 
              President %in% c("Washington", "Jefferson", "Madison")) %>%
    tokens(remove_punct = TRUE) %>%
    tokens_remove(stopwords("english")) %>%
    dfm() %>%
    dfm_group(groups = President) %>%
    dfm_trim(min_termfreq = 5, verbose = FALSE) %>%
    textplot_wordcloud(comparison = TRUE)
```

[image]

I am trying to add a title to this plot, e.g. "My First Plot". Is there a way to add a title to this plot? I can't see a method in the documentation but perhaps there is a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`textplot_wordcloud` uses the base R graphics engine to create the plots. This means you can use the graphics commands to adjust some of the wordcloud features.

After creating the wordcloud, you can just use `title` or `mtext` to add a title to your wordcloud. I used `mtext` because it gives more control over where to place the text on the plot. Using `title` would plot the text over "Jefferson".

```
corpus_subset(data_corpus_inaugural, 
              President %in% c("Washington", "Jefferson", "Madison")) %>%
    tokens(remove_punct = TRUE) %>%
    tokens_remove(stopwords("english")) %>%
    dfm() %>%
    dfm_group(groups = President) %>%
    dfm_trim(min_termfreq = 5, verbose = FALSE) %>%
    textplot_wordcloud(comparison = TRUE)

mtext("my first wordcloud",
      side=3, 
      line=3, 
      at=-0.07, 
      adj=0, 
      cex=1)
```